# Running locally blastn against nt db thru python script

Tags: python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a fasta file with sequence that I want to blast locally to 'nt' database dowloaded on my computer from ncbi website

I dowloaded blast 2.6.0.

In order to access blast from anywhere, I did:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc 

export PATH=/usr/local/ncbi-blast-2.6.0+/bin:$PATH
```

then I did:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then I downloaded 'nt' database (155.6GB) and stored it in /usr/local/blastdb

I want to run in python script this command:

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline

cline = NcbiblastnCommandline(query="/home/proprietaire/Desktop/JADE/stage_scripts/seq_error_fasta.fasta", db="/usr/local/blastdb/nt", evalue=0.001, out="blast_result_local.xml", outfmt=5)
```

But it is not working for a reason. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

'seq_error_fasta.fasta' : is my fasta file with 64 sequences that I want to blast to 'nt' database.

My 'seq_error_fasta.fasta' contains sequence loaded with error like S, J, X so I want to blast them to 'nt' db in order to get the closest better sequence

I found out that I need to format the nt database dowloaded from ncbi so I did this:

makeblastdb -dbtype nucl -in nt

Then I added this after my cline variable in my python script:

stdout, stderr = cline()

The script is running but unfortunately I'm getting this error now:

Bus error (core dumped)

I think it's a ram memory problem so I thought that I need to shorten 'nt' db by taking only the bacteria sequence. I looked on NCBI for a whole bacteria only database but there is multiple database of different species like more then a thousand.

I also tried blast online using this script:

f = open('output_blast.xml','w')

```
for rec in SeqIO.parse(open("seq_error_fasta.fasta"), 'fasta):

       result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", rec.format("fasta"), format_type="XML", alignments=1, perc_ident=95, expect= 0.001)

       f.write(result_handle.read())

f.close()
```

but this only doing one query sequence and returning all hits, althought I specified 1 hit and 95% of identity.

This is driving me crazy lollll Please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question and include necessary details. Is there an error message? Furthermore, formatting the command line pieces in your question appropriately would help other readers to understand the question!

Comment: Try putting `f.write(rec.id + '\n')` before `f.write(result_handle.read())` to make sure that the reason you are getting one query isn't because only one sequence has hits.

Comment: @rookie what happens if you call `print(cline)` and run the command displayed manually?

Answer (score 0):

Download NCBI `nr` database:

```
$ mkdir db 
$ cd db
$ wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nr*
```

Run blast:

```
import io
import shlex
import subprocess

BLAST_OUTFMT6 = """\
    '6 qacc sacc pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore qseq sseq'\
"""

BLAST_OUTFMT6_COLUMN_NAMES = [
    'query_id', 'subject_id', 'pc_identity', 'alignment_length', 'mismatches', 'gap_opens',
    'q_start', 'q_end', 's_start', 's_end', 'evalue', 'bitscore', 'qseq', 'sseq',
]

def blastp(sequence, db, evalue=0.001, max_target_seqs=100000):
    system_command = (
        'blastp -db {db} -outfmt {outfmt} -evalue {evalue} -max_target_seqs {max_target_seqs}'
        .format(db=db, outfmt=BLAST_OUTFMT6, evalue=evalue, max_target_seqs=max_target_seqs)
    )
    cp = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(system_command),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True)
    result, error_message = cp.communicate(sequence)
    if error_message.strip():
        print("Error: {}".format(error_message))
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = blastp('AAAAAAAAAAAAAA', db='/path/to/db/nr')
    print(result)
```